# Jquery in Iframe not working for external div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I write javascript/jquery code in iframe for div that is outside of iframe. It's not working.

here is what i want to run

```
<a id="TextData">Call function which is inside of Iframe</a>

<iframe id="preview-frame">
<script>
 $(function() {
     setTimeout(function(){ alert("hello");
     $("#TextData").html("update with this text");
     }, 1000);
 });
</script>
```

I used timeout every thing but it's not working.

I want to change TextData html using jQuery written in Iframe.

Comment: Is the iframe in same origin ?

Comment: Different origin

Comment: Then no. That's security bummer